# Extract text content from Tika without specifying the file header

Tags: apache-tika

Is there a way to extract content from a file with a Tika server without explicitly defining the header? For example for a specific file named "file.pdf" if I do

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @file.pdf localhost:9998/tika --header "Content-type: application/pdf" > file.txt
```

I get the extracted content in "file.txt" but if I omit the

```
' --header "Content-type: application/pdf" '
```

I get an empty "file.txt".

In general is there a way to automate the process of submitting a document to a tika server and extracting the content in txt with a single command?

Or alternatively how can I use a pipeline to redirect a possible Tika header output answer of a file to the command in the beginning of this question?

Thank you very much community!

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? Tika normally auto-detects the file type for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the Tika Server wrong to get auto-detection. As detailed on the [Tika Server wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), to have the plain text extracted from any file (including PDF) you should run Curl as:

```
curl -T file.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Accept: text/plain"
```

You need an accept header to tell Tika what format you want your result in (Plain Text or HTML for text extraction, more formats available for metadata). As long as you send the file directly with the `-T` option, its type will be auto-detected for you